# CentOS default never fsck root partition on start up?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, fsck

Most documentation or sites will say use "tune2fs -l " to check if the system will do fsck on the system partitions on next boot, in particular, should look at "Mount count" and "Maximum mount count" values. However, I notice for default CentOS 5 or 6 installation, when I check against the root partition, I always noticed something like this from tune2fs output:

```
...
Mount count:              91
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Oct 29 18:48:14 2009
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
...
```

i.e. the max. mount count is set to "-1". That makes me wonder does it mean CentOS (or Red Hat) won't check the root partition at all? I check the fstab, the last number for root partition is still "1" as usual. If the OS does fsck the root partition during startup, how can I tell when (i.e. after how many reboots or when) will the OS will start fsck the root parition during startup?

Answer (score 0):

The fstab line should only make fsck run when the system boots and the filesystem is marked dirty, e.g. after a power failure or system crash.

Using the mount count as a trigger to run fsck is a bloody nuisance, especially on a large filesystems when it always seems to trigger when you're doing  out-of-hours maintenance.